# No sound on HP Chromebook 14 running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, hp, chromebook

I have just installed the OS and there is no sound.  The OS thinks my headphones are a 'Digital Stereo (HDMI)' output

The sound settings only give the following options:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried changing the option in the sound menu to "Analog Output"?

Comment: It only gives me these options: http://imgur.com/a/n2oal

No analogue output option.

Comment: If you have fixed your problem, please post it in the answer "box" below and accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it (for now). What I did was launch alsamixer in the terminal and change the sound card from the default to the intel one, which didn't change anything immediately but after 10 minutes of static the audio worked. But this is Linux, so anything could happen.

Also, don't be freaked out if the laptop does not charge when you go to charge it.  It'll take about 5 minutes to kick in.